# Numpy where matching two specific columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a six column matrix. I want to find the row(s) where BOTH columns match the query.

I've been trying to use numpy.where, but I can't specify it to match just two columns.

```
#Example of the array
x = np.array([[860259, 860328, 861277, 861393, 865534, 865716], [860259, 860328, 861301, 861393, 865534, 865716], [860259, 860328, 861301, 861393, 871151, 871173],])

print(x)

#Match first column of interest
A = np.where(x[:,2] == 861301)

#Match second column on interest
B = np.where(x[:,3] == 861393)

#rows in both A and B
np.intersect1d(A, B)
#This approach works, but is not column specific for the intersect, leaving me with extra rows I don't want.


#This is the only way I can get Numpy to match the two columns, but
#when I query I will not actually know the values of columns 0,1,4,5.
#So this approach will not work.
#Specify what row should exactly look like
np.where(all([860259, 860328, 861277, 861393, 865534, 865716]))
```

```
#I want something like this:
#Where * could be any number. But I think that this approach may be 
#inefficient. It would be best to just match column 2 and 3.

np.where(all([*, *, 861277, 861393, *, *]))
```

I'm looking for an efficient answer, because I am looking through a 150GB HDF5 file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `np.where((x[:, 2] == 861301) & (x[:, 3] == 861393))`.

Comment: yup that worked. I was too close. I was using "and" instead of &. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

you can use a little more advanced slicing, like this:

```py
np.where(np.all(x[:,2:4] == [861277, 861393], axis=1))
```

this will give you only where these 2 cols are equal to `[861277, 861393]`